# pyAudio install error

Tags: pip

I am not able to install pyAudio. It's showing "**Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable**". There are some building wheel error and can't find any youtube video. Please give me a proper working solution.

Comment: A lot more detail needed in order to offer any help. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the exact command you used to try the install? What else is showing with the error, other messages?

Answer (score 0):

To install PyAudio in Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-pyaudio
```